# Acting on the rows in a gridview based on a checkbox field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView, where the first field is a checkbox.  I want to take action client-side (show or hide rows) depending on the state of the checkboxes.

Thanks to [my previous StOf posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147838/handling-radiobuttonlist-with-client-side-scripting), I have a RadioButtonList properly firing my Javascript.  Now it's a matter of obtaining a reference to the appropriate rows.

I have relied on several questions and answers to build my current Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#RadioButtonList1 input[id^=Radio]").click(function () {
        var grd = $("#my_gridview");
        var rows = $("#my_gridview tr:gt(0)");

        switch (this.value) {
            case "All":
                {
                    $("#my_gridview tr").show();
                }

            case "HideRequested":
                {
                    var rowToShow = rows.find("td:eq(0)").filter(checked != "checked");
                    rows.show().not(rowToShow).hide();
                }

            case "ShowRequested":
                {
                    var rowToShow = rows.find("td:eq(0)").filter(checked == "checked");
                    rows.show().not(rowToShow).hide();
                }

        }
    })
});
```

But when I run this, I get an error in the JS console:  **ReferenceError: checked is not defined**.  Which is odd, because it works in the other questions, and the generated HTML (as confirmed in the console) includes the `checked` property in the `input` element.  The HTML is:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" id="gv_grid" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="grGridViewHeader" style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:100px;white-space:nowrap;">Select Entry</th><th scope="col">Entry Name</th><th align="left" scope="col">Type</th><th align="left" scope="col">Details</th>
    </tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:#BED3FC;border-style:None;">
        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                        <input id="gv_grid_chk_selected_0" type="checkbox" name="gv_grid$ctl02$chk_selected" checked="checked" />
                    </td><td>Entry 1</td><td style="font-size:Small;">Foo</td><td style="font-size:Small;">Assorted text.</td>
    </tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:White;border-style:None;">
        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                        <input id="gv_grid_chk_selected_1" type="checkbox" name="gv_grid$ctl03$chk_selected" checked="checked" />
                    </td><td>Entry 2</td><td style="font-size:Small;">Bar</td><td style="font-size:Small;">Assorted text.</td>
    </tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:#BED3FC;border-style:None;">
        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                        <input id="gv_grid_chk_selected_2" type="checkbox" name="gv_grid$ctl04$chk_selected" checked="checked" />
                    </td><td>Entry 3</td><td style="font-size:Small;">Baz</td><td style="font-size:Small;">Assorted text.<br /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have also tried:

```
var checkboxArray = $('#my_gridview td input:checkbox');
```

Which did produce an array of the checkbox elements, but I still couldn't figure out how to correctly filter for the `checked` property nor how to get back to the governing `tr` element.

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013026/2615836

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6068768/2615836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go... http://jsfiddle.net/tdyhq8z7/2/

```
$(function () {
    $("#RadioButtonList1 :radio").click(function () {
        var $rows = $("#gv_grid tr:gt(0)").show();
        switch (this.value) {
            case "HideRequested":
                $rows.filter(function(){
                    return $('td:first>:checkbox',this).is(":checked")
                }).hide();
                break;
            case "ShowRequested":
                $rows.filter(function(){
                    return !$('td:first>:checkbox',this).is(":checked")
                }).hide();
                break;
        }
    })
});

//another solution:
$(function () {
    $("#RadioButtonList1 :radio").click(function () {
        var $rows = $("#gv_grid tr:gt(0)").show(), $val=this.value;
        if(this.value != "All"){
            $rows.filter(function(){
                var $checked = $('td:first>:checkbox',this).is(":checked");
                if($val == "HideRequested") return $checked;
                else if($val == "ShowRequested") return !$checked;
            }).hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thanks.  Please teach me why it works -- what does the `>:` operator do?  It sounds like "search `td` for the element `checkbox`.

Comment: updated $('td>:checkbox',this) to $('td:first>:checkbox',this) to go with only first "td" in "tr".

Comment: $('td:first>:checkbox',this) here "this" referes the current row node "tr". "td:first" gives only first "td" in the "tr". 'td:first>:checkbox' selector gives the "checkbox input element" child(> is child selector) in the "first td" of the "tr". Please refer [http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)